# Why isn't this nested loop generating all the possible outcomes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
for c in [3,6]:
    for s in [1,2]:
        for d in [1,2,3]:
            for z in [2,4,6,8]:
                for x in ['B','C','D','E','F']:
                    for y in ['B','C','D','E','F','G']:
                        print(y,x,z,d,s,c)
```

If I run this, it will not generate all the possible outcomes. Let me explain:
The last digit ( for c in [3,6]) has 2 possible outcomes.. a 3 or a 6. However the program only prints 3.

Comment: It absolutely does print the combinations with 6 at the end.  I tested it.

Comment: Yup, it does. Can't really verify your behavior.

Comment: Python is probably freezing up. When I tried this, it overloaded the python interpreter.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this issue.

Comment: Tested this and found that it will print as expected. It does all the possibilities with c=3 then all the possibilities with c=6

Comment: lgtm! http://ideone.com/Cz0mxI

Comment: It does print out all the combinations, but `c` is the outer most loop, so it will print all of the `3`s for all of the inner loops before it prints out the `6`s.

Comment: As a sidenote, you can make your life easier by doing this: `for c,s,d,z,x,y in itertools.product([3,6], [1,2], [1,2,3], [2,4,6,8], "BCDEF", "BCDEFG"): print(y,x,z,d,s,c)`

Answer (score 1):

Although your code should work, if you, or your computer, are having problems dealing with these deeply nested loops, try using `product()` from `itertools` which simplifies situations like this:

```
from itertools import product

c = [3, 6]
s = [1, 2]
d = [1, 2, 3]
z = [2, 4, 6, 8]
x = ['B','C','D','E','F']
y = ['B','C','D','E','F','G']

for sequence in product(y, x, z, d, s, c):
    print(*sequence)
```

**PARTIAL OUTPUT**

```
B B 2 1 1 3
B B 2 1 1 6
B B 2 1 2 3
B B 2 1 2 6
B B 2 2 1 3
...
G F 8 2 2 6
G F 8 3 1 3
G F 8 3 1 6
G F 8 3 2 3
G F 8 3 2 6
```